# Convert string array to byte array in go

Tags: arrays, go

Given an string array which only contains single characters such as:

```
ex := [...]string{"a","o",".",".","2",".",".","9"}
```

is there a way to get a byte array with same content but with bytes instead of strings?

Comment: is this part of a code-generation workflow?

Comment: @colm.anseo not necessarilly, mostly trying to make the input easier to work with for my purposes, in my case the input I get is guaranteed to be in the form I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) to convert each `string` to a `[]byte`.

```
ex := [...]string{"a", "o", ".", ".", "2", ".", ".", "9"}
var ey [len(ex)][]byte
for i := range ex {
    ey[i] = []byte(ex[i])
}
```

Use this code if your intent is to get a byte array of the joined strings.  This code only works when the strings are single ASCII characters.

```
ex := [...]string{"a", "o", ".", ".", "2", ".", ".", "9"}
var ey [len(ex)]byte
for i := range ex {
    ey[i] = ex[i][0]
}
```

Use this expression of you want to get a slice of bytes of the [joined](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Join) strings: `[]byte(strings.Join(ex[:], ""))`

I don't know the your context for doing this, but my guess is that it's more appropriate to use a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) than an [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types):

```
ex := []string{"a", "o", ".", ".", "2", ".", ".", "9"}
ey := make([][]byte, len(ex))
for i := range ex {
    ey[i] = []byte(ex[i])
}

..

s := []byte(strings.Join(ex, ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   a := [...]string{"a","o",".",".","2",".",".","9"}
   var b [len(a)]byte
   c := strings.Join(a[:], "")
   copy(b[:], c)
   // [8]uint8{0x61, 0x6f, 0x2e, 0x2e, 0x32, 0x2e, 0x2e, 0x39}
   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)
}
```

https://godocs.io/strings#Join

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if this is part of a code-generation pipeline, you can do this a couple of ways.

Directly:

```
bs := [...]byte{'a', 'o', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '9'}
```

or indirectly:

```
ex := [...]string{"a", "o", ".", ".", "2", ".", ".", "9"}

bs := [...]byte{
    ex[0][0],
    ex[1][0],
    ex[2][0],
    ex[3][0],
    ex[4][0],
    ex[5][0],
    ex[6][0],
    ex[7][0],
} // type [8]int8  i.e. [8]byte
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iMEjFpCKAaW

Depending on your use case, these ways may be too rigid. For dynamic initialization methods see the other answers here.